# Jquery each input except those with specific class

Tags: jquery

how to use jquery .each to loop through all input controls except those which have a specific class?

I have the current which loops through all and I want to exclude those with @class="static"

```
    $('input[type = "text"]').each(function () {
        var value = { QuestionId: $(this).attr('id'), Answer: $(this).val() };
        surveyResults.push(value)
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('input[type = "text"]:not(.your-specefic-class)').each(function () {
    var value = { QuestionId: $(this).attr('id'), Answer: $(this).val() };
    surveyResults.push(value)
});
```

Comment: Awe yes, by using not. Thanks!

Comment: If this worked for you. Make sure to mark it as the best answer so others may find it useful.

Comment: This did work for me but I don't see where to accept it as the answer.

Comment: @GoGetSOme This will help you [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)